# Using looping for searching data on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, maps, geojson

Is there a way to find data from different layers and different `propertyName`s? I have several GeoJSON data files, with different properties. At this moment I can only search one GeoJSON.

For looping and calling the data I am using this code:

```
maplink_var = [source1.geojson,source2.geojson,etc]; 

var <?= $i['maplink_var']; ?> = new L.GeoJSON(<?= $i['maplink_var']; ?>, {
  style: function(feature) {
      ...
    },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
      ...
    }
});
```

and below is the code to find data:

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
  layer: source1,source2,source3,
  propertyName: ['propNameSource1','propNameSource2','propNameSource3'],
  marker: false,
  moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
    var zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latlng.layer.getBounds());
    map.setView(latlng, zoom); // access the zoom
  }
});

searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
  e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});
  if(e.layer._popup) e.layer.openPopup();
}).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {
  featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) { 
    featuresLayer.resetStyle(layer);
  }); 
});

map.addControl( searchControl );
```

I get an error if I give array on property name, stack on loading, and none of the data appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search#options) `layer` is a `L.LayerGroup`. Thus you can pass multiple layers like this ([source](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/8fb13e2b7e9e8fbe2554be3879ea2248e4847c3a/examples/multiple-layers.html#L78)):

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
  layer: L.layerGroup([source1, source2, source3]),
  ...
})
```

As for the `propertyName`: The property name must be the same for all GeoJSON files. Try this when you create the `L.GeoJSON` (not tested):

```
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  const p = feature.properties
  p.title = p.propNameSource1 || p.propNameSource2 || p.propNameSource3 //create new property 'title'
}
```

`title` is the default for `propertyName` so you won't even have to set it when you create `L.Control.Search`.